# Html tags won't work in string resource

Tags: android, android-resources

I got this string resource:

```
<string name="about_app_text"><b>%1$s</b> some text.\n\n
        <b>%2$s, text</b>, more text.</string>
```

The text inside the `<b>` tag does not get bold. Why is that?

Comment: please add code where you are converting into html and displaying it into textview

Comment: please go through to this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

Comment: wrap your string with [![CDATA]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
YourTextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string. about_app_text)));
```

**string resource:**

```
<string name="about_app_text"><![CDATA[<b>%1$s</b> some text.\n\n
        <b>%2$s, text</b>, more text.]]></string>
```

Comment: It seems to work, but cancels the affect of the new line character (\n). Do you know why?

Comment: You have exited "string" syntax and have entered into "html" syntax.  Instead of using \n for a new line use the <p></p> tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
<string name="about_app_text"><![CDATA[<b>%1$s</b> some text.\n\n
    <b>%2$s, text</b>, more text.]]></string>
```

then parse as `Spannable`

```
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about_app_text));
textView.setText(Spanned);
```